# Literature on SVG, WebCGM and other vector-formats optimized for browser-display

Tags: svg, vector-graphics, information-retrieval

I'm currently searching for as many material as possible on the formats above for a paper. Currently, all I've come up with are websites concerning the matter, now the question is; are there sophisticated other sources of information on that topic? Preferrably written stuff - I'm especially intereseted in the actual application of such graphic formats for display in browsers and alike.

The main reason is, that I don't want my whole bibliography to be made up with websites -- *profs dun like that no much* -- so I was hoping for some "hard" information, as they say...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the standards for web formats in particular, but file formats in general are written by organisations and published via the internet. For instance, [SVG](http://w3.org/TR/SVG) is under the jurisdiction of [the W3C](http://www.w3.org/Consortium/) as is [WebCGM](http://www.w3.org/TR/webcgm/). I would expect that references to these sorts of organisations should be fine for academics, though make sure you use the permanent links to the exact document you are citing (ie, not the links I've provided which are the 'up to the minute' links).

eg:

```
Bad: http://w3.org/TR/SVG
Good: http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-SVG11-20100622/
```

The main reason for this is that these documents are always under review, and change almost constantly. Keeping printed copies would just be a huge burden and not very helpful in the long run.

Comment: @ApoY2k: For the W3C, if you use the permalink you should be pretty safe from documents changing. For other resources though, you might need to, I don't know. Ask your professors, I suppose